# two paw app extension when used together return the same value

Tags: javascript, paw-app

I built the following extensions to give me random IP and UA data for testing:

https://github.com/tobsn/gd.bacon.PawExtensions.RandomUserAgentDynamicValue
https://github.com/tobsn/gd.bacon.PawExtensions.RandomIPDynamicValue

When I use both in the same request in two different POST variables they both return the same... as you will see in the screenshots, the first executed extension always overwrites the result of the second.

Examples:

[image: IP FIRST]

[image: UA FIRST]

I went through the code a couple times but I couldn't find anything that would let the return values overlap... it's really odd.

Comment: We're definitively aware of this bug. It will be fix in a bugfix version that's coming shortly.

Comment: Ah great, so I'm not just going crazy... I thought for days that maybe I coded it wrong and it's overflowing somehow into the next extension... drove me crazy. ;)

Comment: FYI we're just released Paw 2.2.3 fixing this: http://luckymarmot.com/paw/updates/2.2.3 (on the MAS next week, but already available on the website)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Bug in Paw** - will be fixed soon (state: 09/01/2015)

Comment: Indeed, a bugfix version is coming in the next few days.